# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: on Qt Creator, I am using OSX 10.10.3

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opencv

I am trying to write a UI for an existing *C++* project. In order to modify the code, I have to make sure that the original project can run on *Qt Creator*.

The project requires the use of *opencv*, I am stuck with setting up opencv on *Qt Creator*. I am using *Qt 5.5*, and *opencv 2.4.10*

This is how my `.pro` looks like:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui

TARGET = struck  
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = ap p

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv2
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include


LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib\

-lopencv_core
-lopencv_highgui



SOURCES += \
../../../../struck_qt/src/GraphUtils/GraphUtils.cpp \
../../../../struck_qt/src/Config.cpp \
../../../../struck_qt/src/Features.cpp \
../../../../struck_qt/src/HaarFeature.cpp \
../../../../struck_qt/src/HaarFeatures.cpp \
../../../../struck_qt/src/HistogramFeatures.cpp \
../../../../struck_qt/src/ImageRep.cpp \
../../../../struck_qt/src/LaRank.cpp \
../../../../struck_qt/src/main.cpp \
../../../../struck_qt/src/MultiFeatures.cpp \
../../../../struck_qt/src/RawFeatures.cpp \
../../../../struck_qt/src/Sampler.cpp \
../../../../struck_qt/src/Tracker.cpp

HEADERS += \
../../../../struck_qt/src/GraphUtils/GraphUtils.h \
../../../../struck_qt/src/Config.h \
../../../../struck_qt/src/Features.h \
../../../../struck_qt/src/HaarFeature.h \
../../../../struck_qt/src/HaarFeatures.h \
../../../../struck_qt/src/HistogramFeatures.h \
../../../../struck_qt/src/ImageRep.h \
../../../../struck_qt/src/Kernels.h \
../../../../struck_qt/src/LaRank.h \
../../../../struck_qt/src/MultiFeatures.h \
../../../../struck_qt/src/RawFeatures.h \
../../../../struck_qt/src/Rect.h \
../../../../struck_qt/src/Sample.h \
../../../../struck_qt/src/Sampler.h \
../../../../struck_qt/src/Tracker.h
```

**The error message that I got is following:**

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)", referenced from:
      ImageRep::ImageRep(cv::Mat const&, bool, bool, bool) in ImageRep.o
      LaRank::Update(MultiSample const&, int) in LaRank.o
      LaRank::Debug() in LaRank.o
      LaRank::UpdateDebugImage() in LaRank.o
      _main in main.o
      RawFeatures::UpdateFeatureVector(Sample const&) in RawFeatures.o
      Tracker::Debug() in Tracker.o
      ...
  "cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(double const&)", referenced from:
      ImageRep::ImageRep(cv::Mat const&, bool, bool, bool) in ImageRep.o
      LaRank::UpdateDebugImage() in LaRank.o
      Tracker::Reset() in Tracker.o
      Tracker::UpdateDebugImage(std::__1::vector<Rect<float>, std::__1::allocator<Rect<float> > > const&, Rect<float> const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&) in Tracker.o
  "cv::namedWindow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::open(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)", referenced from:
      ImageRep::ImageRep(cv::Mat const&, bool, bool, bool) in ImageRep.o
      LaRank::Update(MultiSample const&, int) in LaRank.o
      LaRank::UpdateDebugImage() in LaRank.o
      _main in main.o
      RawFeatures::UpdateFeatureVector(Sample const&) in RawFeatures.o
  "cv::Mat::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::release() in ImageRep.o
      cv::Mat::release() in LaRank.o
      cv::Mat::release() in main.o
      cv::Mat::release() in RawFeatures.o
      cv::Mat::release() in Tracker.o
  "cv::Mat::setTo(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      ImageRep::ImageRep(cv::Mat const&, bool, bool, bool) in ImageRep.o
      LaRank::UpdateDebugImage() in LaRank.o
      Tracker::Reset() in Tracker.o
      Tracker::UpdateDebugImage(std::__1::vector<Rect<float>, std::__1::allocator<Rect<float> > > const&, Rect<float> const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&) in Tracker.o
  "cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int)", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::create(int, int, int) in ImageRep.o
      cv::Mat::create(int, int, int) in LaRank.o
      cv::Mat::create(int, int, int) in main.o
      cv::Mat::create(int, int, int) in RawFeatures.o
      cv::Mat::create(int, int, int) in Tracker.o
  "cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&) in ImageRep.o
      cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&) in LaRank.o
      cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&) in LaRank.o
  "cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&, cv::Rect_<int> const&)", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::operator()(cv::Rect_<int> const&) const in LaRank.o
      cv::Mat::operator()(cv::Rect_<int> const&) const in RawFeatures.o
  "cv::flip(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::split(cv::Mat const&, std::__1::vector<cv::Mat, std::__1::allocator<cv::Mat> >&)", referenced from:
      ImageRep::ImageRep(cv::Mat const&, bool, bool, bool) in ImageRep.o
  "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::imshow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      LaRank::Debug() in LaRank.o
      _main in main.o
      Tracker::Debug() in Tracker.o
  "cv::resize(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, double, double, int)", referenced from:
      LaRank::Update(MultiSample const&, int) in LaRank.o
      LaRank::UpdateDebugImage() in LaRank.o
      _main in main.o
      RawFeatures::UpdateFeatureVector(Sample const&) in RawFeatures.o
  "cv::noArray()", referenced from:
      ImageRep::ImageRep(cv::Mat const&, bool, bool, bool) in ImageRep.o
      LaRank::UpdateDebugImage() in LaRank.o
      Tracker::Reset() in Tracker.o
      Tracker::UpdateDebugImage(std::__1::vector<Rect<float>, std::__1::allocator<Rect<float> > > const&, Rect<float> const&, std::__1::vector<double, std::__1::allocator<double> > const&) in Tracker.o
  "cv::waitKey(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)", referenced from:
      ImageRep::ImageRep(cv::Mat const&, bool, bool, bool) in ImageRep.o
      LaRank::UpdateDebugImage() in LaRank.o
      _main in main.o
  "cv::fastFree(void*)", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::~Mat() in ImageRep.o
      cv::Mat::~Mat() in LaRank.o
      cv::Mat::~Mat() in main.o
      cv::Mat::~Mat() in RawFeatures.o
      cv::Mat::~Mat() in Tracker.o
  "cv::integral(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int)", referenced from:
      ImageRep::ImageRep(cv::Mat const&, bool, bool, bool) in ImageRep.o
  "cv::rectangle(cv::Mat&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      LaRank::UpdateDebugImage() in LaRank.o
      rectangle(cv::Mat&, Rect<float> const&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&) in main.o
  "cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const", referenced from:
      ImageRep::ImageRep(cv::Mat const&, bool, bool, bool) in ImageRep.o
      _main in main.o
  "cv::Mat::operator _IplImage() const", referenced from:
      LaRank::UpdateDebugImage() in LaRank.o
  "vtable for cv::_InputArray", referenced from:
      cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Scalar_<double> const&) in LaRank.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "_cvCreateImage", referenced from:
      _drawFloatGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _drawIntGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _drawUCharGraph in GraphUtils.o
  "_cvInitFont", referenced from:
      _drawFloatGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _drawIntGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _drawUCharGraph in GraphUtils.o
  "_cvLine", referenced from:
      _drawFloatGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _drawIntGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _drawUCharGraph in GraphUtils.o
  "_cvNamedWindow", referenced from:
      _showFloatGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _showIntGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _showUCharGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _showImage in GraphUtils.o
  "_cvPutText", referenced from:
      _drawFloatGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _drawIntGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _drawUCharGraph in GraphUtils.o
  "_cvReleaseImage", referenced from:
      _showFloatGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _showIntGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _showUCharGraph in GraphUtils.o
  "_cvSet", referenced from:
      _drawFloatGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _drawIntGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _drawUCharGraph in GraphUtils.o
  "_cvShowImage", referenced from:
      _showFloatGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _showIntGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _showUCharGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _showImage in GraphUtils.o
  "_cvWaitKey", referenced from:
      _showFloatGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _showIntGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _showUCharGraph in GraphUtils.o
      _showImage in GraphUtils.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [struck] Error 1
01:10:53: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project struck (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.0 clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
01:10:53: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

Here are what I have tried and what I am curious about:

**1.** There is a post suggested that do use `-lopencv_core` instead of `-libopencv_core2.4.10` or `libopencv_core`. I tried both, neither worked out.

**2.** If I delete the line:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib\

-lopencv_core
-lopencv_highgui`
```

The error I got was exactly the same as above. I doubt that I didn't include the library successfully.

**3.** A post suggested change `qmake.conf` from `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.X` to `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.10`. I did, and it didn't work.

**4.** If I do:

```
LIBS +=     LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib\

LIBS += -lopencv_core
LIBS += -lopencv_highgui
```

it will claim that the library not found.

I am really concerned about the issue since I really need to set up the project on *Qt Creator* in order to do further work.

If anybody has any idea on how to solve it, please help me out. Thank you !

**NOTE:**
I only put `lopencv_core` and `-lopencv_highgui` there because I have tried include all the titles of opencv libraries there, the error messages are the same.

I double checked that all the `.dylib` files are in `/usr/local/lib`

Comment: The way to indicate that your problem has been solved is to accept an answer. Please don't add the word "SOLVED" to the title or include the answer in the question. If none of the existing answers solve your problem, you can post and accept an answer yourself.

Comment: thank you! I am new to stackoverflow, already accepted the answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to remove your own answer from it. If you think that your answer is significantly different from other answers, feel free to add it - as an answer, not as a question edit.

Comment: thank you! I just want to add some notes that I thought was noteworthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For further reference, you should look at `qmake` manual, since the `.pro` file is used by `qmake` to generate a `Makefile` that is then used by `make` to build your project. The issues you have are completely unrelated to Qt Creator - an IDE that you happen to be using. You're not "configuring" the IDE, but a qmake project.

This is wrong:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib\

-lopencv_core
-lopencv_highgui
```

You need all libraries added to the LIBS variable. The line continuation character `\` merely informs qmake that the following, empty line, is to be a continuation of the `LIBS...` line. Thus, your entry is interpreted as:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
-lopencv_core (junk)
-lopencv_highui (junk)
```

You simply need to put it all on one line, or have line continuations on every line but the last one. The following are all equivalent and correct, and note that whitespaces are important!

```
# way 1
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib \
-lopencv_core \
-lopencv_highui

# way 2
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib\
  -lopencv_core\
  -lopencv_highui

# way 3
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui

# way 4
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib
LIBS += -lopencv_core
LIBS += -lopencv_highui
```

You could also have combinations of these. Their effect is all the same: the `LIBS` configuration entry has three elements added to it (the `-L` element and two `-l` elements).

You must ensure that there exist `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.dylib` and `/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib`. The meaning of `-lFOO` is `libFOO.dylib`.

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE HERE, Problem solved***

here are few things to clarify:

**The correct way to include libraries is:**

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib\
        -lopencv_core\
        -lopencv_highgui
```

make sure that libopencv_coreX.X.X.dylib (and other .dylib) files are in the folder/usr/local/lib

make sure you write 
    -lopencv_core
instead of
    -libopencv_core2.4.10(2.4.10 is just an version)

make sure you did indent for each library that you want to include, for example:

```
 LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib\
 -lopencv_core\
 -lopencv_highgui
```

is **WRONG**, by doing this, I got an error says "Extra characters after test expression"

By doing exactly what Kuba Ober suggested below, after I fixed these, everything just work perfectly fine!